# retrieving data from database sql query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to get data from db. **vName** is a column where `vName=ADMIN_EMAIL`, and this row has a column whose name is **vValue**. There is also a column which stores **email address**, I want to get that value and store it in `$toEmail`.

Kindly Someone guide me.

Here is my **php code**

```
   $sqldata=mysqli_query($obj,"SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE     vName='ADMIN_EMAIL'");
   $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sqldata);
   // $toEmail = "dev.waqas@designbee.us";
   $mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["userName"] . "<". $_POST["userEmail"] .">\r\n";
   if(mail($toEmail, $_POST["subject"], $_POST["content"], $mailHeaders)) {
       echo "<p class='success'>Mail Sent.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p class='Error'>".$toEmail.".</p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch data after executing query.

```
$row = $sqldata->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$toEmail= $row['vName']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to fetch query result. `mysql_num_rows()` gives you number of row exist in query result.
Check below code.

```
 $sqldata=mysqli_query($obj,"SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE vName='ADMIN_EMAIL'");
 $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sqldata);
 if($rowcount > 0)
 {
     $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqldata);
     $toEmail = $result['email']; // Your table column value
     $mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["userName"] . "<". $_POST["userEmail"] .">\r\n";
     if(mail($toEmail, $_POST["subject"], $_POST["content"], $mailHeaders)) {
         echo "<p class='success'>Mail Sent.</p>";
     } else {
         echo "<p class='Error'>".$toEmail.".</p>";
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fetch records from db, which you have not done :

```
 $sqldata=mysqli_query($obj,"SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE vName='ADMIN_EMAIL'");
       $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sqldata);
    if($rowcount > 0)
    {
       $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqldata); // fetch records
       $toEmail = $result['vemail']; // Your column name
       $mailHeaders = "From: " . $_POST["userName"] . "<". $_POST["userEmail"] .">\r\n";
       if(mail($toEmail, $_POST["subject"], $_POST["content"], $mailHeaders)) {
           echo "<p class='success'>Mail Sent.</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p class='Error'>".$toEmail.".</p>";
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use PDO,

```
try{
      $con=new PDO("mysql::host=localhost;dbname=databasename;","username","password");
      $query="SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE vName='ADMIN_EMAIL";
      $res=$con->query($query);
      $rows=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
      $email="";
      foreach($rows as $row)
      {
         $email.=$row["useremail"];//you get the user email in the var $email
      }          
//do what you want ....
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die("error:".$e->getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: How it is better. Please explain

Comment: It's just a personal preference.

Comment: Well then it's not better if it's a personal preference, is it?

Comment: Mysqli is just for Mysql use, but PDO is generale,PDO supports 12 different drivers, opposed to MySQLi, which supports MySQL only.

Comment: So knowing how to deal with PDO, is better than knowing how to deal with Mysqli only.